# Lower bound of a trigonometric integral

Tags: real-analysis, probability, analysis, integral-equations

Let $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$ be non-zero real numbers. Further, suppose that $f$ and $g$ are probability density functions defined on $\mathbb{R}$. I'm interested in computing a lower bound of the quantity $\alpha\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}\cos(vx)f(v)dv+\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}\left(\beta\cos(vx)+\gamma\sin(vx)\right)g(v)dv$, where $x\in\mathbb{R}$. I'm aware of the fact that both $\sin$ and $\cos$ functions have a range of $[-1,1]$ and that the probability density functions have integrals equal to 1. I suspect that the inequality $x\geq -|x|$, for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, will be helpful in handling $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$. For example, $\alpha\geq -|\alpha|$, etc. In fact, I've established the lower bound $-(|\alpha|+|\beta|+|\gamma|)$. However, I'm not convinced that my reasoning is watertight. All suggestions are welcome.

Comment: $-(|\alpha|+|\beta|+|\gamma|)$ is clearly a lower bound and $(|\alpha|+|\beta|+|\gamma|)$ is an upper bound, but there may be tighter bounds, at least when $\beta$ and $\gamma$ are both non-zero.

Comment: Do you have any additional information about the densities $f$ and $g$?

Comment: @sudeep5221 Other than what's already given, no.

Comment: Are $f,g$ known function? (a tighter bound can be possibly obtained)

Comment: @NN2 No, they are not.

Answer (score 0):

Denote $$\sin\left(\theta \right):=\frac{\beta}{\sqrt{\beta^2 +\gamma^2}}$$
then
$$I= \alpha\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}\cos(vx)f(v)dv+\sqrt{\beta^2 +\gamma^2}\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}\sin(vx +\theta)g(v)dv$$
$$\implies \color{red}{-|\alpha|- \sqrt{\beta^2 +\gamma^2}\le I \le |\alpha|+ \sqrt{\beta^2 +\gamma^2}} \tag{1}$$

**Given the fact that only $\alpha,\beta$ and $\gamma$ are known, the bounds $(1)$ are tightest** in the sense that they can be reached:

- For the lower bound, let us define
  $$\begin{align}
  &f(v)=\delta_{\{v=\pi  \}} \iff\cases{ \mathbb{P}(V=\pi)=1\\ \mathbb{P}(V\ne \pi)=0} \\
  &g(u)=\delta_{\{u=\pi/2 - \theta  \}} \iff\cases{ \mathbb{P}(U=\pi/2 - \theta)=1\\ \mathbb{P}(U\ne \pi/2 - \theta)=0} \\
  &x = 0
  \end{align}$$
  then the lower bound is reached.
- For the upper bound, similarly let us define
  $$\begin{align}
  &f(v)=\delta_{\{v=0  \}} \iff\cases{ \mathbb{P}(V=0)=1\\ \mathbb{P}(V\ne 0)=0} \\
  &g(u)=\delta_{\{u=-\pi/2 - \theta  \}} \iff\cases{ \mathbb{P}(U=-\pi/2 - \theta)=1\\ \mathbb{P}(U\ne -\pi/2 - \theta)=0} \\
  &x = 0
  \end{align}$$
  then the upper bound is reached.

Comment: So it would appear that the bounds established in (1) are attained only if the pdfs are Dirac 'distributions' (point masses). That is too bad. Do you think that it may be possible to tighten the upper bound in (1) to 0, IF we play with specific f and g? If you do, I would like to see what your line of thinking is. Thanks!

Comment: @user775349 no, as the equalities can be reached, the bounds are then the tightest bounds.

Comment: As evident in (1), the integral $I$ is bounded between a negative and a positive real number.  Let us say that one wanted to focus only on the negative $I$. Seeing that there is no way to tune $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$ to achieve this, how would you phrase this? Would you say 'assume that $I<0$', and then simply proceed with whatever analysis you wanted to carry out?